# local variable 'archivo' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

When trying to do a try and except part in my code y get this error

> local variable 'archivo' referenced before assignment

**The code is the following:**

```
archivo=open(os.getcwd()+"/proxies.txt",'r')
def get_data(url):
    try:
        separados=archivo[0].split(":")
        datos_proxy="socks5://"+separados[2]+":"+separados[3]+":"+separados[0]+":"+separados[1]
        proxy={"sock5": datos_proxy}
        r = s.get(url,proxies=proxy)
        r.html.render(sleep=3)
        links=r.html.absolute_links
        for link in links:
            if "0x" in link:
                if "assets" in link:
                    if "matic" not in link:
                        hook.send(link)
    except:
        archivo=archivo[1:]
```

Gives me the error in the "separadores" variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing the global `archivo` varible that lies outside of the get_data function.

Either open the file in the function or write `global archivo` before the try statement.

See here [Global Variables w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp)